# How do I set the minimum width of a subfigure?

Tags: tikz-pgf, subfloats, width

I have:

```
\subfigure[blah blah blah.]
{
\begin{tikzpicture}[/MyStyle]
    ... some stuff...
\end{tikzpicture} 
}
```

But "some stuff" is not that wide and the text in the subfigure produces a lot of underfull hboxes.  I want to make the subfigure wider.  How do I do that?

Comment: Probably this question was asked before tex.stackexchange.com was created but now is available I think this should be moved there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A general approach for customizing the width and the height of a subfigure is using the [`adjustbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) package. It provides features for trimming (also with negative value, so enlarging), clipping, scaling, rotating etc. which can be applied also to TikZ pictures.

An example where the subfigure has been made wider by 1 cm on the left and on the right:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\subfloat{Test figure}
\subfloat[The ball]{%
  \trimbox{-1cm 0cm -1cm 0cm}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node[circle,shading=ball,ball color=red!80!white,minimum size=2cm] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}}}
\subfloat{Test figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Without `\trimbox:`

[image: subfigures]

With `\trimbox`:

[image: widened subfigure]

Answer (score 2):

You could alter the width of the tikz picture. I don't know if subfigure itself has any width attribute. It normally inherits its size from whatever is inside it, as far as I know

Comment: How do I alter the width of a tikz picture?

Comment: (I have been inserting blank nodes, but this is ugly.)

Comment: You can use something like
\useasboundingbox (-1,-1) rectangle (4,4);
to grow (or shrink) the space a tikz picture takes.  The actual picture is not changed.  Of course you can also grow/shrink the picture itself with a 
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]

Comment: Can tikz pictures not just take a `width=...` argument?

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use the `subfigure` environment from the `subcaption` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.09\textwidth}
\centering
\rule{30pt}{20pt}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.8\textwidth}
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node[circle,shading=ball,ball color=red!80!white,minimum size=2cm] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{The ball}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.09\textwidth}
\centering
\rule{30pt}{20pt}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]